# Running a batch file to backup Desktop and My Documents to a shared location

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have 50 machines on domain and I wanted to do a backup of their desktop and my documents folder to a shared drive on network.

I wrote a batch file and added it to all computer through GPO/schedule tasks. It worked for few some of them but for some of them it pops up a question saying either they cant create directory or whether its a directory or not and asks for a prompt "d"

Please see what I am running

```
ECHO off

mkdir "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\Desktop"
mkdir "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\My Documents"

xcopy "%userprofile%\Desktop" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\Desktop" /E /Y /Q
xcopy "%userprofile%\Documents" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\My Documents" /E /Y /Q

Exit
```

What will be the best way to achieve the same goal with less trouble?

Is there a way I can pass on the value d and press enter in this code?

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
xcopy /?
```

It says in part

```
Copies files and directory trees.

NOTE: Xcopy is now deprecated, please use Robocopy.
```

While there also see the /i switch.

```
/I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
             assumes that destination must be a directory.
```

Also specifing filenames works better.

```
xcopy "%userprofile%\Desktop\*.*" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\Desktop\*.*" /E /Y /Q
xcopy "%userprofile%\Documents\*.*" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\My Documents\*.*" /E /Y /Q
```

So type

```
robocopy /?
```

and

```
robocopy.doc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me suggestions. I will first try first option before going in to robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing backslash on the target tells xcopy that the target is a directory, and the directories will be automatically created.

Use a filespec on the source folders.

```
@echo off
xcopy "%userprofile%\Desktop\*.*" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\Desktop\" /E /Y /Q
xcopy "%userprofile%\Documents\*.*" "\\Serv\Local_Backup\%username%\My Documents\" /E /Y /Q
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try and see how it performs.